# Entity Framework Core exclude INNER JOIN

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have an issue with nested entities:

```cs
public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}
public class Department {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IList<Person> People { get; set; } = new List<Person>();
}

public IAsyncEnumerable<Person>? ReadPersons()
{
    return _dbContext.Persons?
            .Include(p => p.Department)
            .AsAsyncEnumerable();
}

public IAsyncEnumerable<Person>? ReadDepartments()
{
    return _dbContext.Departments?
            .Include(d => d.People)
            .AsAsyncEnumerable();
}
```

When I read the `Person` with Entity Framework Core it includes `People` to `Department` ...

But what if I want to exclude `People` in case when I read `ReadPerson` and include `People` in case when I `ReadDepartment` ?

Is it possible ?

Comment: What's `ReadPerson` / `ReadDepartment`?

Comment: @GertArnold Methods using which I read `Person` and `Department`

Comment: If your question is: can I stop EF from doing relationship fixup, you can't.

Comment: @GertArnold But why ??? In some cases it can improve performance ... (

Comment: Use `AsNoTracking()` if you're worried about performance and tracking isn't important. Even then, EF will perform relationship fixup per LINQ query.